# Getting into PathView delegate

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to animate a property within my PathView delegate once it comes into view.

```
    Component {
        id: pathViewDelegate
        Item {
            Text {
                id: tempText
                color: "red"
                text: "test"
            }

            function intoView() {
                myAnimation.start()
            }

            SequentialAnimation {
                id: myAnimation
                PropertyAnimation {duration: 1000; target: tempText; properties: "color"; to: "green"}
                PropertyAnimation {duration: 1000; target: tempText; properties: "color"; to: "yellow"}
            }
        }
    }
```

The only way I know how to display my PathView correctly (like a linear carousel) is to have the currentItem clipped off screen. In other words, the displayed item is always currentIndex+1 in my PathView.

```
    PathView {
        id: mainCarousel
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        interactive: false
        highlightMoveDuration: 300

        clip: true

        model: pathViewModel
        delegate: pathViewDelegate

        path: Path {
            startX: -mainCarousel.width*0.5
            startY: mainCarousel.height/2

            PathLine { x: mainCarousel.width*0.5; y: mainCarousel.height/2 }
            PathLine { x: mainCarousel.width*(mainCarousel.count-0.5); y: mainCarousel.height/2 }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when I try to implement a function with "mainCarousel.currentItem.intoView()", it animates the item clipped off screen. I know there isn't a way to do "currentItem+1", but is there some other workaround?

EDIT: Full example code

```
ListModel {
    id: pathViewModel
    ListElement {header: "text 1"}
    ListElement {header: "text 2"}
    ListElement {header: "text 3"}
    ListElement {header: "text 4"}
}
Component {
    id: pathViewDelegate

    Item {
        width: mainCarousel.width
        height: mainCarousel.height

        Text {
            color: "red"
            text: header
        }

        function runAnimation() {
            myAnimation.start()
        }

        SequentialAnimation {
            id: myAnimation
            PropertyAnimation {property: "color"; to: "green"; duration: 1000}
            PropertyAnimation {property: "color"; to: "yellow"; duration: 1000}
            PropertyAnimation {property: "color"; to: "purple"; duration: 1000}
        }
    }
}
PathView {
    id: mainCarousel
    width: 500
    height: 500

    interactive: false
    highlightMoveDuration: 300

    clip: true

    model: pathViewModel
    delegate: pathViewDelegate

    path: Path {
        startX: -mainCarousel.width*0.5
        startY: mainCarousel.height/2

        PathLine { x: mainCarousel.width*0.5; y: mainCarousel.height/2 }
        PathLine { x: mainCarousel.width*(mainCarousel.count-0.5); y: mainCarousel.height/2 }
    }
}
MouseArea {
    id: telltaleMouseArea
    anchors.fill: mainCarousel
    onClicked: {
        mainCarousel.incrementCurrentIndex()
        mainCarousel.currentItem.runAnimation()
    }
}
```

The initial item displayed is "text 2". The currentItem is "text 1", initially. In the code, when the MouseArea is clicked, "text 2" animates, but it is off screen. I am just trying to animate the item that is in view, when it becomes into view.

Comment: the title and the text do not correspond to each other. What is your real problem? For what you need the `currentIndex+1` workaround?

Comment: In my code example, the delegate has a function which I want to fire when the item comes into view (which happens on a key press event). If I do mainCarousel.currentItem, then the item that is affected is off screen (clipped).

Comment: @brandon provide a **[mcve]**

Comment: first move your `currentItem` into view: `startX: mainCarousel.width*0.5`

Comment: When you have your animation on `color` the animation doesn't know which color to animate. Putting the `Animation` inside the `Text`, now the animation knows. It's also a good practice to use appropriate animation, in here `ColorAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

Change the animation to the following:

```
Text {
    color: "red"
    text: header

    SequentialAnimation on color{
        id: myAnimation
        ColorAnimation {
            to: "green"
            duration: 1000
        }
        ColorAnimation {
            to: "yellow"
            duration: 1000
        }
        ColorAnimation {
            to: "purple"
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

and make sure your `currentItem` is in view with : `startX: mainCarousel.width*0.5`